# How do I find all outcomes for shuffling two strings whilst keeping the order of each string?

Tags: python

How can I find all iterations of shuffling two strings `x` and `y`:

```
x = "ab"
y = "cd"
shuffle(x, y)
```

Which will return:

```
['abcd', 'acbd', 'acdb', 'cabd', 'cadb', 'cdab']
```

Which keeps the order of each string i.e `ab` and `cd` but shuffles in with the other string at any point.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: There is nothing wrong with `shuffle(x,y)`.  And the question does have example input and output.

Comment: @ScottHunter You're correct, I was reading that as shuffling in an additional, third string.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Misunderstandings aside, we're not a code writing service. Please review [ask] and show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Mayneman Do you want two sets of results? 1. Which will return: ['abcd', 'acbd', 'acdb', 'cabd', 'cadb', 'cdab']  2. Which keeps the order of each string i.e ab and cd but shuffles in with the other string at any point.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution template:

```
def shuffle(x,y):
    if x=='': #nothing left in x to shuffle
        return [y]
    if y=='': #nothing left in y to shuffle
        return [x]
    else:
        # Everything in the result begins either with x[0] or y[0]
        # All results that start with x[0] come from shuffling the strings that remain after removing x[0]
        # Similar idea for y[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def printshuffle(x, xi, y, yi, result):
    if xi == len(x) and yi == len(y):
        print(result)    
    elif xi == len(x):
        printshuffle(x, xi, y, yi+1, result+y[yi]) 
    elif yi == len(y):
        printshuffle(x, xi+1, y, yi, result+x[xi])
    else:
        printshuffle(x, xi+1, y, yi, result+x[xi])
        printshuffle(x, xi, y, yi+1, result+y[yi])

def shuffle(x, y):
    result=""
    printshuffle(x, 0, y, 0, result)

# main
x="ab"
y="cd"
shuffle(x, y)
```

It's like combine two sorted array into one sorted array.